# Using sqlite3 in a multi-threaded Ruby application

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I want to write a GUI application in Ruby that will use SQLite to store data.

This will mean that at some points I will spawn some threads in Ruby that will update the database, and possibly there will be more than one concurrent thread that accesses and/or updates the database.

I understand though that SQLite, though it can be compiled for thread support, is not so by default.

If it is not, what kind of problems can I expect to occur? What should I look out for, and how should I anticipate to mitigate them?

Comment: afaik the database-file will be locked during write operations, multithreaded or not.

Comment: Does this mean that other threads would be blocked, or will they fail?

Comment: there is a retry and timeout loop